# how to use pandas for condition selection

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this

```
AREA     AMOUNT
A         1000
A          10
B          30
B         3000
C          22
D         300
```

What I want to get is more that 100 in AREA A & more than 100 in AREA B & less than 100 in AREA C and more than 100 in AREA D . I have many of these kind of area to analyse.
so what I want to get is below.

```
AREA     AMOUNT
A         1000
B         3000
C          22
D         300
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.isin()` and pass the three columns `> 100` and then `==` for just the `C` column using `&` and `|` for `and` and `or`. Pay attention to parentheses here:

```
df = df[((df['AREA'].isin(['A','B','D'])) & (df['AMOUNT'] > 100)) |
        ((df['AREA'] == 'C')              & (df['AMOUNT'] < 100))]
df
Out[1]: 
  AREA  AMOUNT
0    A    1000
3    B    3000
4    C      22
5    D     300
```

Comment: Thank you it's a fast way to solve my problem and can add new condition easily in this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can write in this way also by creating custom function for setting up the condition

```
import operator
ops = {'eq': operator.eq, 'neq': operator.ne, 'gt': operator.gt, 'ge': operator.ge, 'lt': operator.lt, 'le': operator.le}
g = lambda x, y, z: (df['AREA'].eq(x)) & (ops[z](df['AMOUNT'], y))
```

---

```
df[g('A', 100, 'gt')| g('B', 100, 'gt') | g('C', 100, 'lt') | g('D', 100, 'gt') ]
```

---

```
   AREA AMOUNT
0   A   1000
3   B   3000
4   C   22
5   D   300
```

Comment: thank you this is very easy to set the new condition !